# Passing id value to action class

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, struts2, lightbox

I want to pass textfield with `id` value `pat` to the `getautocomplete.action` in Struts 2. Here I am using `TINY.box` to pop up the next page.

```
<s:textfield  name="pat" id="pat"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
  T$('tiny_patient').onkeypress = function(){
    TINY.box.show('getautocomplete.action',1,0,0,1)
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to append the id `pat` and its value to the url that you pass to the `show` function. For example

```
var url = 'getautocomplete.action?pat=' + $("#pat").val();
```

You can then use the variable `url` in your `show` function.

You also need to add the following in your action class. This also depends on the java type of pat. I am using `String`,

```
private String pat;

public String getPat()
{
    return pat;
}

public void setPat(final String value)
{
    this.pat = value;
}
```

**Note**
It is recommended to get your url using the following instead of hard-coding the extension

```
<s:url id="url_variable" namespace="/namespace_of_action" action="action_name" />
var url = '<s:property value="url_variable" />?pat=' + $("#pat").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to populate the box based on previous box selection or any server side process you have to use **ajax**.

In your action class , write a getter-setter for variable named "pat" like this:

private string pat;

```
public getPat()
{
.........
}

public setPat(String pat)
{
this.pat=pat;
}
```

and change

```
TINY.box.show('getautocomplete.action',1,0,0,1)
```

to

```
TINY.box.show('getautocomplete.action?pat="xyz"',1,0,0,1)
```

Hope this will solve your problem unless you have an idea about ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<s:textfield  name="pat" id="pat"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("tiny_patient").onkeypress = function(e){
    TINY.box.show("<s:url action='getautocomplete'/>"+"?pat="+document.getElementById("pat").value,1,0,0,1)
  }
</script>
```

Comment: The use of plain javascript like `document.getElementById` is usually not advisable. Instead use javascript libraries like `jQuery`.

Comment: @UchennaNwanyanwu yes, but OP didn't use JQuery in the question. And your answer even if you use JQuery doesn't handle `keypress` event.